# Custom 500 error page not called during POST requests

Tags: c#, razor-pages, .net-core-3.0

My razor pages app uses a custom error page for 500 errors (I force a production environment for the purposes of testing)

```
public class Startup
{
     ...
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          }
          else
          {
               app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
               app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");

               // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
               app.UseHsts();
          }
          ...
```

I have a razor page with the following code

```
public void OnGet()
{
    throw new Exception("testing GET");
}

public void OnPost()
{
    throw new Exception("testing POST");
}
```

If I send a GET request to the page, I am redirected to the 500 error page as I would expect.

However, if I send a POST request I don't see the error page, although I do get a response code of 500.

I have added breakpoints to the code and the correct methods are being called.

Is there some configuration which filters out POST requests from the error pages?

Answer (score 0):

As normally happens, I figured out the answer after posting the question here!

(StackOverflow is a great demonstration of the Rubber Duck principal).

It's because there was no `OnPost()` method in the code-behind of the error page.